# How to do merge (with groupby) and fill in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have two data frames and I am trying to do groupby merge and fill rows.

The first is a data frame with 5 rows:

```py
Likeliness = pd.DataFrame(['Like','Dislike','Somewhat liked', 'Somewhat disliked','Neutral'], columns =['Likeliness'])
```

The second is a data frame `DF` that is similar to this snippet:

[image: Data]

The desired output after merge and fill is [image: Output data].

I am able to manage the merge with this code

```py
data_updated = DF.groupby(['Date','Name','Book', 'Course']).apply(
    lambda y: pd.merge(y, Likeliness, how='outer'))
```

and able to get output but I need to fill in other information in `groupby` with 'Date','Name','Book', 'Course' and with the exception of `Course` value to 0.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please show us your expected output

Comment: Its in the question above. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using `fillna` just for `Course` then do `ffill` to fill other columns.

```
data_updated = (DF.groupby(['Date','Name','Book', 'Course'])
                .apply(lambda y: pd.merge(y, Likeliness, how='outer'))
                .fillna({'Course': 0})
                .ffill()
                .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach, you can try this :

```
def complete(df):
    out = pd.merge(df, Likeliness, how="outer")
    ff_cols = df.columns.difference(["Course"])
    out.loc[:, ff_cols] = out.loc[:, ff_cols].ffill()
    return out.fillna(0, downcast="infer")
​
data_updated = (
    DF.groupby(list(DF.columns.difference(["Likeliness"], sort=False)),
               group_keys=False).apply(complete)
)
```

Output :

```
print(data_updated)

         Date         Likeliness   Name           Book  Course
0  2022-06-06               Like    Bob  Reinforcement       1
1  2022-06-06            Dislike    Bob  Reinforcement       1
2  2022-06-06            Neutral    Bob  Reinforcement       1
3  2022-06-06     Somewhat liked    Bob  Reinforcement       0
4  2022-06-06  Somewhat disliked    Bob  Reinforcement       0
0  2022-06-20               Like  Cathy    Mathematics       1
1  2022-06-20            Dislike  Cathy    Mathematics       0
2  2022-06-20     Somewhat liked  Cathy    Mathematics       0
3  2022-06-20  Somewhat disliked  Cathy    Mathematics       0
4  2022-06-20            Neutral  Cathy    Mathematics       0
```